# Ruby: ARGV breaks accented characters

Tags: ruby, unicode, encoding, argv

```
# encoding: utf-8
foo = "Résumé"
p foo
```

**> "Résumé"**

```
# encoding: utf-8
ARGV.each do |argument|
    p argument
end
```

**test.rb Résumé** > "R\xE9sum\xE9"

Why does this occur, and how can I get ARGV to return "Résumé"?

I have **chcp 65001** set already and am using **ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]**

**EDIT** After asking around on irc, I was instructed to do `chcp 1252>NUL` which fixed the problem.

Comment: Seems that your terminal doesn't send UTF-8 encoded strings to ruby.

Comment: `p argument.encoding` returns **#<Encoding:UTF-8>** and 
`puts argument` returns **R�sum�**

Comment: Right, Ruby accepts given string as UTF-8 encoded. But it isn't.

Answer (score 7):

For some reason, Windows doesn't use UTF-8 in your console. So, although Ruby expects UTF-8 encoded string, it gets Windows-1252 encoded string.

So you have several possibilities (which I can't test as I, fortunately, don't use Windows):

1. Persuade Windows to use UTF-8 in your console. I don't know if `chcp` should work and, if so, why it doesn't.
2. Tell Ruby to use Windows-1252 instead of UTF-8 as default
3. Convert ARGV from Windows-1252 to UTF-8 manually:

Example:

```
>> argument = "R\xE9sum\xE9"
=> "R\xE9sum\xE9"
>> argument.force_encoding('windows-1252').encode('utf-8')
=> "Résumé"
```